# Iterating through an array of Perl Hashes

Tags: json, perl, curl, jira

I have written a perl script which accessed JIRA REST API to GET a list of issues that match a specific JQL query. Sometimes thee results are only one issue and other times I get many back.

```
$client->GET(
$apiPath.$jql.$fieldRes,
$headers);

#a perl hash of results 
my $response = from_json($client->responseContent());
```

while $response is a perl hash, if I try to drill down into the hash I hit an issue.

There is an array of "issues" within the hash.

I am trying to pull data with "foreach" for each specific issue but I keep getting errors:

```
foreach my $issues ($response->{'issues'})
{
      print STDERR Dumper($issues->{'key'});
}
```

Error...

```
Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at script.pl line #.
Argument "JIRA-10011" isn't numeric in hash element at script.pl line #.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at script.pl line #.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the datatype of `$response->{issues}`?

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; print(Dumper($response));`?

Comment: $response is a perl hash and I cannot display the data but response issues is an ARRAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is an array of "issues" within the hash.

You cannot put arrays into hashes in Perl, this is only possible for array references. So you need to dereference it when iterating the hash(ref) with your `foreach`.

```
foreach my $issues ( @{ $response->{'issues'} } )
{
  print STDERR Dumper($issues->{'key'});
}
```

Since you will get one issue per iteration, you should rename `$issues` to `$issue` so you won't get confused later.